# Set schedule cron job in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cron

I have set a cron job

```
* * * * * php /var/www/html/laravel schedule:run 1>> /var/www/html/log_laravel 2>&1
```

This is what I have set in `app\console\Kernel.php`

```
namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
use App\Http\Controllers\DataController;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{

    protected $commands = [
    ];


    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->call(function () {
            DataController::get_data();
        })->everyMinute();
    }


}
```

Is that it? In [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scheduling) there isn't anything else but this is not working. 
`DataController@get_data` should perfom some updates in database (I can also call this manually by going to `http//www.site.com/public/data/get_data`. How can I debug this? I don't have anything in log file in `storage/logs` and my `log_laravel` for Cron job is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reference the path to `artisan.php` script:

```
* * * * * php /var/www/html/laravel/artisan schedule:run 1>> /var/www/html/log_laravel 2>&1
```

I do not recommend writing output to any logs, this will run every minute, and will kill your disk space.

Comment: I will remove it, I was just trying to see why it doesn't work

Comment: Yep, just waiting for time restriction. Thank you

Comment: great, glad to help.